# Error Correction Using Java Library

Tags: java, error-correction

In my project, Automatically, errors need to be corrected using appropriate substitute. I tried  **Jazzy Libray**(http://sourceforge.net/projects/jazzy/) it gives a list of substitutes. But it does not show the best suitable one

> example: byt:->>> byte, bat, bet, but, by......

From this list, to select a suitable word we can use levenshtein distance, n gram analysis. But it doesn't consider the context of the sentence or keyboard structure(QUERTY `byt-->but` this should be the best choice when we consider only keyboard mistakes). Is their any java libraries or projects that consider Keyboard edit distance of two words. what would be the best  approach to find best correction for a misspelled word?

Comment: Not a Java library, but this link might be interesting: [Custom Distance metric for handling Typographical errors optimized for a QWERTY keyboard](http://findsomethingnewtoday.wordpress.com/2013/07/20/986/)

Comment: neither n gram nor levenshtein or "dictionary attacks" have anything to do with "error correction" ... i think you you need to do some research on your own topic, you're completely using the wrong words. What you want is SPELL CHECKING - thats something completely different.

Comment: i am completely OK with you. Jazzy is a SPELL Checking library. but it will return a list of possible words. what i wanted to know is is their any metrics to consider Qwerty keyboard typographical mistakes.